# Difference of two date time in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Is there any way to take the difference between two `datetime` in sql server?

For example, my dates are

1. `2010-01-22 15:29:55.090`
2. `2010-01-22 15:30:09.153`

So, the result should be `14.063 seconds`.

Comment: You're getting all the `datediff` answers but none seems to remind you that you might get negative results from it depending on the parameter ordering.

Answer (score 103):

Just a caveat to add about DateDiff, it counts the number of times you pass the boundary you specify as your units, so is subject to problems if you are looking for a precise timespan.
e.g.

```
select datediff (m, '20100131', '20100201')
```

gives an answer of 1, because it crossed the boundary from January to February, so even though the span is 2 days, datediff would return a value of 1 - it crossed 1 date boundary.

```
select datediff(mi, '2010-01-22 15:29:55.090' , '2010-01-22 15:30:09.153')
```

Gives a value of 1, again, it passed the minute boundary once, so even though it is approx 14 seconds, it would be returned as a single minute when using Minutes as the units.

Answer (score 33):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF (MyUnits, '2010-01-22 15:29:55.090', '2010-01-22 15:30:09.153')
```

Substitute "MyUnits" based on [DATEDIFF on Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql)

Answer (score 23):

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(day, '2010-01-22 15:29:55.090', '2010-01-22 15:30:09.153')
```

Replace `day` with other units you want to get the difference in, like `second`, `minute` etc.

Answer (score 20):

I can mention four important functions of  MS SQL Server that can be very useful:

1) The function [DATEDIFF()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189794.aspx) is responsible to calculate differences between two dates, the result could be "**year quarter month dayofyear day week hour minute second millisecond microsecond nanosecond**", specified on the first parameter (**datepart**):

```
select datediff(day,'1997-10-07','2011-09-11')
```

2) You can use the function [GETDATE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188383.aspx) to get the actual time and calculate differences of some date and actual date:

```
select datediff(day,'1997-10-07', getdate() )
```

3) Another important function is [DATEADD()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186819.aspx), used to convert some value in datetime using the same **datepart** of the datediff, that you can add (with positive values) or substract (with negative values) to one base date:

```
select DATEADD(day,  45, getdate()) -- actual datetime adding 45 days
select DATEADD(  s,-638, getdate()) -- actual datetime subtracting 10 minutes and 38 seconds
```

4) The function [CONVERT()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187928.aspx) was made to format the date like you need, it is not parametric function, but you can use part of the result to format the result like you need:

```
select convert(  char(8), getdate() ,   8) -- part hh:mm:ss of actual datetime
select convert(  varchar, getdate() , 112) -- yyyymmdd
select convert( char(10), getdate() ,  20) -- yyyy-mm-dd limited by 10 characters
```

DATETIME cold be calculated in seconds and one interesting result mixing these four function is to show a formated difference um hours, minutes and seconds (**hh:mm:ss**) between two dates:

```
declare  @date1 datetime, @date2 datetime
set @date1=DATEADD(s,-638,getdate())
set @date2=GETDATE()

select convert(char(8),dateadd(s,datediff(s,@date1,@date2),'1900-1-1'),8)
```

... the result is **00:10:38** (638s = 600s + 38s = 10 minutes and 38 seconds)

Another example:

```
select distinct convert(char(8),dateadd(s,datediff(s, CRDATE , GETDATE() ),'1900-1-1'),8) from sysobjects order by 1
```

Answer (score 13):

I tried this way and it worked. I used SQL Server version 2016

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,'2010-01-22 15:29:55.090', '2010-01-22 15:30:09.153')/1000.00;
```

Different DATEDIFF Functions are:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year,        '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(quarter,     '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(month,       '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(dayofyear,   '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,         '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(week,        '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour,        '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,      '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(second,      '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(millisecond, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 7):

Ok we all know the answer involves `DATEDIFF()`. But that gives you only half the result you may be after. What if you want to get the results in human-readable format, in terms of Minutes and Seconds between two `DATETIME` values?

The `CONVERT()`, `DATEADD()` and of course `DATEDIFF()` functions are perfect for a more easily readable result that your clients can use, instead of a number.

i.e.

```
CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, date1, date2), 0), 114)
```

This will give you something like:

> HH:MM

If you want more precision, just increase the `VARCHAR()`.

```
CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, date1, date2), 0), 114)
```

> HH:MM.SS.MS

Comment: I think in the example for more precision you also need to change the 'minute' to 'second'

Comment: Oh, and this does not include days. I would expect select CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2021-02-16 18:41:31.677', '2021-02-17 20:52:51.671'), 0), 114)  to output 26:11:20:000 but instead it output 02:11:20:000

Answer (score 5):

Internally in SQL Server dates are stored as 2 integers. The first integer is the number of days before or after the base date (1900/01/01). The second integer stores the number of clock ticks after midnight, each tick is 1/300 of a second.

[More info here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-are-dates-stored-in-sql-server)

Because of this, I often find the simplest way to compare dates is to simply substract them. This handles 90% of my use cases. E.g.,

```
select date1, date2, date2 - date1 as DifferenceInDays
from MyTable
...
```

When I need an answer in units other than days, I will use [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

Comment: Note that this only applies to the old `DATETIME` type, not to `DATE`, `TIME`, or `DATETIME2`.  Also, the value returned will be another `DATETIME`, so you'll need to cast it to get the human-readable number of days between dates.

Comment: Can you really just do `date2 - date1`? Most the RDBMS systems I'm trying this in won't work.

Comment: @M.R. Yes, for SQL Server this works.

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of ways to look at a date difference, and more when comparing date/times.  Here's what I use to get the difference between two dates formatted as "HH:MM:SS":

```
ElapsedTime AS
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, StartDate, EndDate)        / 3600 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':'
    + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, StartDate, EndDate) % 3600 /   60 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':'
    + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, StartDate, EndDate) %   60        AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
```

I used this for a calculated column, but you could trivially rewrite it as a UDF or query calculation.  Note that this logic rounds down fractional seconds; 00:00.00 to 00:00.999 is considered zero seconds, and displayed as "00:00:00".

If you anticipate that periods may be more than a few days long, this code switches to D:HH:MM:SS format when needed:

```
ElapsedTime AS
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(S, StartDate, EndDate) >= 359999
        THEN
                          CAST(DATEDIFF(S, StartDate, EndDate) / 86400        AS VARCHAR(7)) + ':'
            + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, StartDate, EndDate) % 86400 / 3600 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':'
            + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, StartDate, EndDate) %  3600 /   60 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':'
            + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, StartDate, EndDate) %    60        AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
        ELSE
              RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, StartDate, EndDate)        / 3600 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':'
            + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, StartDate, EndDate) % 3600 /   60 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':'
            + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, StartDate, EndDate) %   60        AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
        END
```

Answer (score 5):

The following query should give the exact stuff you are looking out for.

```
select datediff(second, '2010-01-22 15:29:55.090' , '2010-01-22 15:30:09.153')
```

Here is the link from MSDN for what all you can do with datediff function .
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(yyyy, '2011/08/25', '2017/08/25') AS DateDiff
```

It's gives you difference between two dates in **Year**

Here (2017-2011)=6 as a result

Syntax:

```
DATEDIFF(interval, date1, date2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use This for `DD:MM:SS`:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), Datediff(dd, '2019-08-14 03:16:51.360', 
         '2019-08-15 05:45:37.610')) 
       + ':' 
       + CONVERT(CHAR(8), Dateadd(s, Datediff(s, '2019-08-14 03:16:51.360', 
         '2019-08-15 05:45:37.610'), '1900-1-1'), 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

So this isn't my answer but I just found this while searching around online for a question like this as well.  This guy set up a procedure to calculate hours, minutes and seconds.  The [link](http://sqlserverbuddy.blogspot.com/2011/06/hour-minute-second-between-two-date.html) and the code:

```
--Creating Function
If OBJECT_ID('UFN_HourMinuteSecond') Is Not Null
Drop Function dbo.UFN_HourMinuteSecond
Go
Exec(
'Create Function dbo.UFN_HourMinuteSecond
(
@StartDateTime DateTime,
@EndDateTime DateTime
) Returns Varchar(10) 
As
Begin

Declare @Seconds Int,
@Minute Int,
@Hour Int,
@Elapsed Varchar(10)

Select @Seconds = ABS(DateDiff(SECOND ,@StartDateTime,@EndDateTime))

If @Seconds >= 60 
Begin
select @Minute = @Seconds/60
select @Seconds = @Seconds%60

If @Minute >= 60
begin
select @hour = @Minute/60
select @Minute = @Minute%60
end

Else
Goto Final 
End

Final:
Select @Hour = Isnull(@Hour,0), @Minute = IsNull(@Minute,0), @Seconds =               IsNull(@Seconds,0)
select @Elapsed = Cast(@Hour as Varchar) + '':'' + Cast(@Minute as Varchar) + '':'' +     Cast(@Seconds as Varchar)

Return (@Elapsed)
End'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @dt1 datetime='2012/06/13 08:11:12', @dt2 datetime='2012/06/12 02:11:12'

select CAST((@dt2-@dt1) as time(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

PRINT DATEDIFF(second,'2010-01-22 15:29:55.090','2010-01-22 15:30:09.153')

Answer (score 1):

```
select
datediff(millisecond,'2010-01-22 15:29:55.090','2010-01-22 15:30:09.153') / 1000.0 as Secs

result:
Secs
14.063
```

Just thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION getDateDiffHours(@fdate AS datetime,@tdate as datetime)
RETURNS varchar (50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cnt int
    DECLARE @cntDate datetime
    DECLARE @dayDiff int
    DECLARE @dayDiffWk int
    DECLARE @hrsDiff decimal(18)
    
    DECLARE @markerFDate datetime
    DECLARE @markerTDate datetime
    
    DECLARE @fTime int
    DECLARE @tTime int 
    
    
    DECLARE @nfTime varchar(8)
    DECLARE @ntTime varchar(8)
    
    DECLARE @nfdate datetime
    DECLARE @ntdate datetime
    
    -------------------------------------
    --DECLARE @fdate datetime
    --DECLARE @tdate datetime

    --SET @fdate = '2005-04-18 00:00:00.000'
    --SET @tdate = '2005-08-26 15:06:07.030'
    -------------------------------------
    
    DECLARE @tempdate datetime
    
    --setting weekends
    SET @fdate = dbo.getVDate(@fdate)
    SET @tdate = dbo.getVDate(@tdate)
    --RETURN @fdate 

    SET @fTime = datepart(hh,@fdate)
    SET @tTime = datepart(hh,@tdate)
    --RETURN @fTime 
    if datediff(hour,@fdate, @tdate) <= 9
    
            RETURN(convert(varchar(50),0) + ' Days ' + convert(varchar(50),datediff(hour,@fdate, @tdate)))  + ' Hours'
    else
    --setting working hours
    SET @nfTime = dbo.getV00(convert(varchar(2),datepart(hh,@fdate))) + ':' +dbo.getV00(convert(varchar(2),datepart(mi,@fdate))) + ':'+  dbo.getV00(convert(varchar(2),datepart(ss,@fdate)))
    SET @ntTime = dbo.getV00(convert(varchar(2),datepart(hh,@tdate))) + ':' +dbo.getV00(convert(varchar(2),datepart(mi,@tdate))) + ':'+  dbo.getV00(convert(varchar(2),datepart(ss,@tdate)))
    
    IF @fTime > 17 
    begin
        set @nfTime = '17:00:00'
    end 
    else
    begin
        IF @fTime < 8 
            set @nfTime = '08:00:00'
    end 
    
    IF @tTime > 17 
    begin
        set @ntTime = '17:00:00'
    end 
    else
    begin
        IF @tTime < 8 
            set @ntTime = '08:00:00'
    end 

    
    
    -- used for working out whole days

    SET @nfdate = dateadd(day,1,@fdate) 

    SET @ntdate = @tdate
    SET @nfdate = convert(varchar,datepart(yyyy,@nfdate)) + '-' + convert(varchar,datepart(mm,@nfdate)) + '-' + convert(varchar,datepart(dd,@nfdate))
    SET @ntdate = convert(varchar,datepart(yyyy,@ntdate)) + '-' + convert(varchar,datepart(mm,@ntdate)) + '-' + convert(varchar,datepart(dd,@ntdate))
    SET @cnt = 0
    SET @dayDiff = 0 
    SET @cntDate = @nfdate
    SET @dayDiffWk = convert(decimal(18,2),@ntdate-@nfdate)
    
    --select @nfdate,@ntdate

    WHILE @cnt < @dayDiffWk
    BEGIN   
        IF (NOT DATENAME(dw, @cntDate) = 'Saturday') AND (NOT DATENAME(dw, @cntDate) = 'Sunday')
        BEGIN 
            SET @dayDiff = @dayDiff + 1
        END 
        SET @cntDate = dateadd(day,1,@cntDate)
        SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
    END 
    
    --SET @dayDiff = convert(decimal(18,2),@ntdate-@nfdate) --datediff(day,@nfdate,@ntdate)
    --SELECT @dayDiff
    
    set @fdate = convert(varchar,datepart(yyyy,@fdate)) + '-' + convert(varchar,datepart(mm,@fdate)) + '-' + convert(varchar,datepart(dd,@fdate)) + ' ' + @nfTime
    set @tdate = convert(varchar,datepart(yyyy,@tdate)) + '-' + convert(varchar,datepart(mm,@tdate)) + '-' + convert(varchar,datepart(dd,@tdate)) + ' ' + @ntTime
    
    set @markerFDate = convert(varchar,datepart(yyyy,@fdate)) + '-' + convert(varchar,datepart(mm,@fdate)) + '-' + convert(varchar,datepart(dd,@fdate)) + ' ' + '17:00:00'
    set @markerTDate = convert(varchar,datepart(yyyy,@tdate)) + '-' + convert(varchar,datepart(mm,@tdate)) + '-' + convert(varchar,datepart(dd,@tdate)) + ' ' + '08:00:00'
    
    --select @fdate,@tdate
    --select @markerFDate,@markerTDate
    
    set @hrsDiff = convert(decimal(18,2),datediff(hh,@fdate,@markerFDate))
    
    --select @hrsDiff
    set @hrsDiff = @hrsDiff +  convert(int,datediff(hh,@markerTDate,@tdate))

    --select @fdate,@tdate  
    
    IF convert(varchar,datepart(yyyy,@fdate)) + '-' + convert(varchar,datepart(mm,@fdate)) + '-' + convert(varchar,datepart(dd,@fdate)) = convert(varchar,datepart(yyyy,@tdate)) + '-' + convert(varchar,datepart(mm,@tdate)) + '-' + convert(varchar,datepart(dd,@tdate))  
    BEGIN
        --SET @hrsDiff = @hrsDiff - 9
        Set @hrsdiff = datediff(hour,@fdate,@tdate)
    END 
    
    --select FLOOR((@hrsDiff / 9))
    
    IF (@hrsDiff / 9) > 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @dayDiff = @dayDiff + FLOOR(@hrsDiff / 9)
        SET @hrsDiff = @hrsDiff - FLOOR(@hrsDiff / 9)*9
    END 

    --select convert(varchar(50),@dayDiff) + ' Days ' + convert(varchar(50),@hrsDiff)   + ' Hours'

    RETURN(convert(varchar(50),@dayDiff) + ' Days ' + convert(varchar(50),@hrsDiff))    + ' Hours'

END
```

Comment: Can you explain your code according to the question?

Answer (score 1):

**Sol-1:**

```
select 
  StartTime
  , EndTime
  , CONVERT(NVARCHAR,(EndTime-StartTime), 108) as TimeDiff 
from 
  [YourTable]
```

**Sol-2:**

```
select 
  StartTime
  , EndTime
  , DATEDIFF(hh, StartTime, EndTime)
  , DATEDIFF(mi, StartTime, EndTime) % 60 
from 
  [YourTable]
```

**Sol-3:**

```
select 
  DATEPART(hour,[EndTime]-[StartTime])
  , DATEPART(minute,[EndTime]-[StartTime]) 
from 
  [YourTable]
```

Datepart works the best

Answer (score 1):

Please check below trick to find the date difference between two dates

```
 DATEDIFF(DAY,ordr.DocDate,RDR1.U_ProgDate) datedifff
```

where you can change according your requirement as you want difference of days or month or year or time.

Answer (score 0):

For Me This worked Perfectly
Convert(varchar(8),DATEADD(SECOND,DATEDIFF(SECOND,LogInTime,LogOutTime),0),114)

and the Output is 
HH:MM:SS which is shown accurately in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
DECLARE @articleDT DATETIME;
DECLARE @nowDate DATETIME;
 
-- Time of the ARTICLE created
SET @articleDT = '2012-04-01 08:10:16';
 
-- Simulation of NOW datetime
-- (in real world you would probably use GETDATE())
SET @nowDate = '2012-04-10 11:35:36';
 
-- Created 9 days ago.
SELECT 'Created ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(day, @articleDT, @nowDate) AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ' days ago.';
 
-- Created 1 weeks, 2 days, 3 hours, 25 minutes and 20 seconds ago.
SELECT 'Created '
    + CAST(DATEDIFF(second, @articleDT, @nowDate) / 60 / 60 / 24 / 7 AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ' weeks, '
    + CAST(DATEDIFF(second, @articleDT, @nowDate) / 60 / 60 / 24 % 7 AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ' days, '
    + CAST(DATEDIFF(second, @articleDT, @nowDate) / 60 / 60 % 24  AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ' hours, '
    + CAST(DATEDIFF(second, @articleDT, @nowDate) / 60 % 60 AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ' minutes and '
    + CAST(DATEDIFF(second, @articleDT, @nowDate) % 60 AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ' seconds ago.';
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way to subtract two `datetime` values in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @startTime datetime = '2010-01-22 15:29:55.090';
DECLARE @stopTime  datetime = '2010-01-22 15:30:09.153';

SELECT @stopTime - @startTime AS ElapsedTime
```

```
ElapsedTime
-----------------------
1900-01-01 00:00:14.063

(1 row affected)
```

Tested: SQL Server 2000, 2019

Answer (score -1):

For MS SQL, you can convert the datetime value to a double value.
The integer part contains the number of days since 1900-01-01, the fractional part contains the time in hours.
So you can calculate date difference as:
cast(date1-date2 as FLOAT)