# converting time in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to get getting  Between 15 minutes and 1 hour.  the below SQL is what I have come up with using TIMESTAMPDIFF. How i am getting an error of 'TIMESTAMPDIFF' is not a recongnized built-in function name.

My SQL

```
SELECT Name, count(*)
FROM [test.database]
where TME between '2018-10-01 00:00:00.000' and '2019-01-31 00:00:00.999'
and TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date_trunc('SECOND', DT), date_trunc('SECOND', TME)) >= 900
and TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date_trunc('SECOND', DT), date_trunc('SECOND', TME)) < 3600
group by Name 
order by Name
```

could someone help me to make my SQL work please.

thankS

Comment: **`TIMESTAMPDIFF`** is not a built-in function in `sql-server`

Comment: what else can i use? any suggetions?

Comment: You have this tagged with sql server. Your error message sounds like sql server. But your code is filled with mysql functions.

Comment: @SeanLange and the `[]` look like sql server. It was tagged with both mysql and sql server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference of two date time in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116540/difference-of-two-date-time-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you are using SQL Server and want `datediff()`.  However, I would use `dateadd()`.

The initial date comparisons look quite cumbersome.  I don't see why you would want the ending to be up to one second into Jan 31.  So I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
select Name, count(*)
from [test.database]
where TME >= '2018-10-01' and
      TME < '2019-01-31' and
      TME >= dateadd(SECOND, 900, DT) and
      TME <= dateadd(SECOND, 3, DT) 
group by Name 
order by Name
```

Comment: If it is indeed sql server `[test.database]` is going to give an error (unless the table actually contains a dot).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, count(*)
FROM [test.database]

where (TME between '2018-10-01 00:00:00.000' and '2019-01-31 00:00:00.999')
and (datepart(SECOND,TME) between 15 and 60)
group by Name 
order by Name
```