# Calculate time difference in two different dates SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have two column - start_time and end_time in my sql database. Below is my data

```
start_time: 2019-09-17 06:00:00.000 
end_time: 2019-09-18 06:00:00.000
```

When i run this query:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(5),(end_time-start_time),108) from activity
```

it returns 00:00

I need the output to be 24:00. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference of two date time in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116540/difference-of-two-date-time-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output format you want is non standard, because it isn't really time (e.g. the hours component could exceed 24).  One option would be to use `DATEDIFF` in minutes mode and then tease out the hours and minutes components:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEDIFF(minute, '2019-09-17 06:00:00', '2019-09-19 06:13:00') / 60) +
    ':' +
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEDIFF(minute, '2019-09-17 06:00:00', '2019-09-19 06:13:00') % 60) AS hours
```

This outputs: `48:13`

### Demo

Comment: Doesn't work also. It returns a blank when i replace string with column name SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEDIFF(minute, start_time, end_time) / 60) +
    ':' +
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEDIFF(minute, start_time, end_time) % 60) from ACTIVITY

Comment: @ThaiThai Well it works in the demo, making me suspect that your data is what the problem is.

Comment: my bad. i deleted my data which is why it shows blank

Answer (score 1):

try with `datediff` function

```
select datediff(hh,'2019-09-17 06:00:00.000','2019-09-18 06:00:00.000')
```

so in your case it would be

```
select datediff(hh,start_time,end_time) from activity
```

Comment: Doesn't work. it returns a blank when i run select datediff(hh, start_time, end_time) FROM ACTIVITY

Comment: @ThaiThai https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dbd8eceeccf198e45fa214378208166a see the link

Comment: my bad. i deleted my data which is why it shows blank

Answer (score 1):

`select case` will do.

```
select case when Format(end_time-start_time, 'HH:mm', 'en-US') = '00:00' then '24:00' else 
    Format(end_time-start_time, 'HH:mm', 'en-US') end from activity
```