# Mssql time between calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I want to get the Time from a SQL Server DateTime column. I want to only time between calculation.Date not important only important hour,minute and seconds

| Workstart | Personelnum |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.2022 07:35:13 | 13021 |
| 01.01.2022 08:12:15 | 17058 |

My query:

```
Select case when cast(time,workstart) between '07:15:00' and '08:30:00' then 08:00:00 end ,Personelnum 
from table;
```

Should be Result:

| Workstart | Personelnum |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.2022 08:00:00 | 13021 |
| 01.01.2022 08:00:00 | 17058 |

How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try?  (It hink I can ask because of "I want to only time between and usıng case when in select"), and because of not having read: [How do I ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which says "[Search, and research](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Search%2C%20and%20research)"

Comment: I tink this is a duplicate of: [Difference of two date time in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116540/difference-of-two-date-time-in-sql-server)

Comment: Hi @Luuk thanks for answer.I dont want different.I want to change time and hours.example workstart=01.01.2022 08:23:52 ı want to result= 01.01.2022 08:00:00 my condıtıosn if time 07:00 between 09:00 should be 08:00

Comment: Maybe you should read: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and rephrase the question?   (Yes, I know, English is a difficult language...)

Comment: I just joined here. I will learn the format. Sorry for my English level.

Comment: That doesn't look like a SQL Server datetime value. Also, what version of SQL Server may be important here, as the `Time` data type is a relatively recent addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're using SQL Server 2012 or newer you can use the TIME datatype to get what you're looking for.

```
DECLARE @PunchClock TABLE (PunchID INT IDENTITY, WorkStart DATETIME, PersonelNum INT)
INSERT INTO @PunchClock(WorkStart, PersonelNum) VALUES
('2022-01-01 07:35:13.000', 13021),
('2022-01-01 08:12:15.000', 17058),
('2022-01-01 07:14:59.000', 12345),
('2022-01-01 08:30:01.000', 12345)

SELECT DATEADD(SECOND,CASE WHEN CAST(WorkStart AS TIME) BETWEEN '07:15' AND '08:30' THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND,CAST(WorkStart AS TIME),'08:00') ELSE 0 END,WorkStart) AS WorkStart, PersonelNum
  FROM @PunchClock
```

```
WorkStart               PersonelNum
-----------------------------------
2022-01-01 08:00:00.000 13021
2022-01-01 08:00:00.000 17058
2022-01-01 07:14:59.000 12345
2022-01-01 08:30:01.000 12345
```

This case expression converts the `DATETIME` to a `TIME` and produces the `DATEDIFF` in `SECONDS` to your specified time when it falls within your range. We then just added the difference is seconds to the `DATETIME` from the table. I added an extra couple of rows to show how rows outside of the range are not affected.

Edit:

If you want to get really clever, you could also use a lookup table to define the adjustments you want, like this:

```
DECLARE @PunchClock TABLE (PunchID INT IDENTITY, WorkStart DATETIME, PersonelNum INT)
INSERT INTO @PunchClock(WorkStart, PersonelNum) VALUES
('2022-01-01 07:35:13.000', 13021),
('2022-01-01 08:12:15.000', 17058),
('2022-01-01 07:14:59.000', 12345),
('2022-01-01 08:30:01.000', 12345),
('2022-01-01 23:35:00.000', 12345),
('2022-01-01 23:59:01.000', 12345)

DECLARE @AdjustmentTimes TABLE (StartTime TIME, EndTime TIME, AdjustToTime TIME, Modifier INT)
INSERT INTO @AdjustmentTimes (StartTime, EndTime, AdjustToTime, Modifier) VALUES
('07:15', '08:30',    '08:00',    0),
('23:35', '23:59:59', '23:59:59', 1)

SELECT DATEADD(SECOND,DATEDIFF(SECOND,CAST(WorkStart AS TIME),COALESCE(a.AdjustToTime,CAST(WorkStart AS TIME)))+COALESCE(a.Modifier,0),WorkStart) AS WorkStart, PersonelNum
  FROM @PunchClock p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @AdjustmentTimes a
      ON CAST(p.WorkStart AS TIME) BETWEEN a.StartTime AND a.EndTime
```

To add new adjustments you'd just need a corresponding row in the adjustments table.

Comment: Hi Patric , Can I specify one more time frame in addition to my question?     
     Workstart                     
02.01.2022 23:45:13 
Should be result :                      
03.01.2022 00:00:00 Is it possible for us to add this?if the time range is between 23:35 and 23:59, write it one day later

Comment: Sure, if you follow the same pattern as in the answer you can add as many adjustments as you'd like: `WHEN CAST(WorkStart AS TIME) BETWEEN '23:35' AND '23:59:59' THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND,CAST(WorkStart AS TIME),'23:59:59')+1 ` I added +1 to make sure it crosses the date bound.

Answer (score 0):

`cast(time,workstart)` is not the correct syntax. A cast operation is `cast(value as type)`, so it should be `cast(workstart as time)`. This is basic stuff you should be able to do on your own.

The other issue is you have to add the time back to base date value.

I'd tend solve this by converting to seconds since midnight, like this:

```
dateadd(second, case when datediff(second, cast(workstart as date), workstart) between 26100 and 30600 then 28800 else datediff(second, cast(workstart as date), workstart)  end, cast(cast(workstart as date) as datetime))
```

This is because I've been working with SQL since long before the `time` data type existed, and because `time` is explicitly defined as a time of day and **not** as a timespan, meaning it's still a little weird to compose a datetime result from separate date and time values (you have to make sure they are both datetime values first):

```
cast(cast(workstart as date) as datetime) + cast(case when cast(workstart as time(0)) between '07:15:00' and '08:30:00' then '08:00:00' else cast(workstart as time(0)) end as datetime) as TimeOfDayFinal
```

See both options work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/z8EGuDkH

The link also shows how I found the seconds values to use in the first sample.

Comment: The last `else workstart` in the final expression above is not quite right for cases outside the selected time range, such as '20220101 11:00:00'. I expect you either intended `else cast(workstart as time(0))` or you meant to have the date math contained entirely within the `then` part.

Comment: @TN Yes, you are right. I was hoping to avoid that, because it also means another cast back to datetime for that side of the addition operation, but oh well.